# Comparing a list of csv files against a list of csv files-Python

Tags: python, list, csv, comparison

Here is the code snippet :-

```
import csv
import sys

f1_name = "Result1.csv"
f2_name = "Result2.csv"
f1 = open(f1_name,'r').readlines()
f2 = open(f2_name,'r').readlines()

count1 = 0
for line in f1:
    result = line.strip("\n")
    count1+=1
    if line != "\n" and line in f2:
        print "Line({0}) in {1} found in Line{2} in {3}({4})".format(
        str(result),
        f1_name,
        str(1+f2.index(line)),
        f2_name,
        line.strip())
```

So far, the code is comparing the two csv files and generating output in the following format:-

```
    Line(1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8  ) in Result1.csv found in Line2 in Result2.csv(1  6  1  1  516405  0  21  8)
Line(1  6  1  1  516405  21  8  ) in Result1.csv found in Line4 in Result2.csv(1  6  1  1  516405  21  8)
Line(1  6  1  1  21  34  ) in Result1.csv found in Line6 in Result2.csv(1  6  1  1  21  34)
Line(1  6  1  21  60  ) in Result1.csv found in Line8 in Result2.csv(1  6  1  21  60)
```

But This the comparison between only two files. I have 50 csv files to be compared against 50 csv files.

So I have two lists:-

```
list1 = [Result1.csv, Result2.csv...Result50.csv]
list2 = [Gen1.csv, Gen2.csv....Gen.csv]
```

How can I modify my code and compare Result1.csv to Gen1.csv, Result2.csv to Gen2.csv and so on?

So the desired output would be the same but It will have a heading such as :-

```
Comparing Result1.csv to Gen1.csv
(Same output mentioned above)
Comparing Result2.csv to Gen2.csv
(output)
```

and so on..

Comment: if you have 50 cv. draw two at a time and place temp compared file and compare that with other

Comment: why are  you casting to str and using string formatting?

Comment: There is a tool called diff that does this, or you could use python's difflib.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the two list zip it and perform

```
import csv
import sys


list1 = ['Result1.csv', 'Result2.csv'...'Result50.csv']
list2 = ['Gen1.csv', 'Gen2.csv'....'Gen.csv']

for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    f1_name = i
    f2_name = j
    f1 = open(f1_name,'r').readlines()
    f2 = open(f2_name,'r').readlines()

    count1 = 0
    for line in f1:
        result = line.strip("\n")
        count1+=1
        if line != "\n" and line in f2:
            print "Line({0}) in {1} found in Line{2} in {3}({4})".format(
            str(result),
            f1_name,
            str(1+f2.index(line)),
            f2_name,
            line.strip())
        else:
            if line != "\n":
                print line,'-this is not found in file2'

    f1.close()
    f2.close()
```

Comment: if your downvoting.please put a comment and make me learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: Thanks sundar for the effort. I wanted to ask one more thing. How can I handle my code if something is mis matching or not found. Currently it only works if exact data is found in both the csv files.

Comment: do you want to print the unmatched files from both like a-b and b-a

Comment: Yeah in the same way as its comparing and giving the output 'found in', if there is something mismatching lets suppose is Result1.csv has an extra field in it which is not in Gen1.csv, so it should give the same out but 'NOT FOUND' instead of 'found'

Comment: and yeah, comparison should be other way round too:)

Comment: @sam: Please refrain from asking significant additional questions here in the comments...